# Object Mapping issue with RESTKit+Swift

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I am facing an object mapping issue using RestKit and Swift when trying to print an error description. Below is the code I am using to map the error with RestKit:

```
let errorObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: MyErrorModelClass.self) 
    errorObjectMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray([
        "reason",
        "errorMessage"
])
let errorCodes = NSMutableIndexSet()
    errorCodes.addIndexes(RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)))
    errorCodes.addIndexes(RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassServerError)))

objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(
    mapping: errorObjectMapping,
    method: RKRequestMethod.Any,
    pathPattern: nil,
    keyPath: "error",
    statusCodes: errorCodes))
```

Code block where I am printing the Error description :

```
failure: { (objectRequestOperation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    println("error \(error).")
    }
```

Printing description of error:

```
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1004 <MyErrorModelClass: 0x17023bc00>" UserInfo=0x17406e480 {RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
"<MyErrorModelClass: 0x17023bc00>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In failure block I want to display the actual error in AlertView, but getting object type response.

When I am replacing 

       'let errorObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: MyCustomClassError.self)'

With 
        'let errorObjectMapping: RKObjectMapping = RKObjectMapping.requestMapping()'

The Printing description of error is: 
**Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1004 "<null>" UserInfo=0x170860040 {RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
        {
        reason = "An error occurred. Please try again shortly.";
    }
), NSLocalizedDescription=<null>}**

Comment: I don't see what your problem is, you just haven't finished writing the code yet. Add the alert to use the error

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get your custom error object from the RestKit NSError object. I think you can achieve this using:

```
let customError = error.userInfo?[RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey] as? MyErrorModelClass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **RestKit v2.x** you should access your error object in this way:

```
if let errorMessage = error.userInfo?[RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey]?.firstObject as? MyErrorModelClass{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the calls to show it in an alertView.

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
```